# Implement password_compat

Tags: php, validation, authentication, pdo, cryptography

I have properly implemented the creation of the hash with this library only changing the cost value. Now I am stuck on actually verifying the user. For my current system I also have to check if the user is activated and then also start a session. This is what I have :

```
 <?php 
require('core/init.php');

// Required field names
$required = array('username', 'password');

// Loop over field names, make sure each one exists and is not empty
$error = false;
    foreach($required as $field) {
        if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
        $error = true;
        }
    }
//This is what will make the password 
$form_password = $_POST['password'];
$hash = password_hash($form_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    if ($error) {
        echo "Please Check username and password field!";
    }
        else { 
                if (password_verify($form_password, $hash)) {
                    $member_username = $_POST['username'];
                    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :user");
                    $query->bindParam(':user', $member_username);
                    $query->execute();
                    $row = $query->fetch();

                        if($row['activated'] > 0){
                            $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row['user_id'];
                            header("location: login_success.php");

                            }   else {
                                    echo "Account not activated wait for system administrator!";

                                }


                } else {
                            Echo "Wrong password or username please <a href='index.php'><bold>Retry!</bold></a>";

                        }


        }
```

What I have done is run a query if the password verify actually is true. that query then fetchs the row activated to check if the value is greater then 0, if not then the user is not activated.

however my error is that no matter what I enter I keep getting Wrong password or username please retry!

and I know the password and user are not incorrect. I am second guessing myself as to if I have properly implemented the verification part of password_compat.

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Edit :

Question answered by dev-null-dweller in comments.

The problem : I didn't realise I couldn't use library $password and $hash variables as a global. So to fix it I created the variables and all is working fine. thank you!

Comment: Where does `$password` and `$hash` come from?

Comment: it comes from from the password.php file included with the password_compat library. https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php

Comment: This is a library, it does not set any global variables. I'm asking if you are aware that both `$password` and `$hash` are undefined in your code.

Comment: You sir are awesome. Thank you so much. If you would like you can answer the question. Again thank you!

Comment: This is not a real question and it will be closed as such.

Comment: @markus-tharkun I don't understand what you mean its "not a real question"?

Comment: It's an oversight or a lack of general understanding, not a real problem... apart from that it's also not of any help to the community at large (not constructive).

Comment: Not going to argue this with you, however I would like to include that there are people out there who are new this (like me) that are not pros (like you) and if proper documentation does not exist then where else to turn to? Ever heard of the saying "never a stupid question just a stupid answer"?

Comment: @RaGe10940 Not implying anything about your specific question. But that saying is as flawed as they get. Believe me: there are lots of stupid questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `$password` and `$hash` are undefined in your code. As for `$password` you can get it from `$_POST`, but `$hash` comes from database, so you have to query it before verifying password:

```
if ($error) {
    echo "Please Check username and password field!";
} else {
    $member_username = $_POST['username'];
    $form_password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :user");
    $query->bindParam(':user', $member_username);
    $query->execute();
    $row = $query->fetch();
    if (!$row || !password_verify($form_password, $row['password'])) {
        if ($row['activated'] > 0) {
            $options = array(/* Your current hashing options */);
            $algorithm = PASSWORD_BCRYPT;
            if (password_needs_rehash($row['password'], $algorithm, $options)) {
                $hash = password_hash($row['password'], $algorithm, $options);
                /* Store new hash in db */
            }
            $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row['user_id'];
            header("location: login_success.php");
        } else {
            echo "Account not activated wait for system administrator!";
        }
    } else {
        Echo "Wrong password or username please <a href='index.php'><b>Retry!</b></a>";
    }
}
```

Comment: What I did was just create the $hash variable with : $hash = password_hash($form_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT); as the same as in register_script.php and it worked just fine.

Comment: bcrypt is not a hashing algorithm, you have to get the hash and run a verify on the password and the encrypted password from the database, if you're using bcrypt. Everytime you use bcrypt on one given password, the encrypted version will look different. Therefore you can't do a simple comparison, you have to let bcrypt do that with verify, as I said.

Comment: @RaGe10940 sorry but now I don't really know what are you doing, but I feel you are doing it totally wrong...

Comment: Code has been edited. based on the readme page from https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/README.md it specifies that to verify password "simply call: (password_verify) am I reading this wrong?

Comment: You are reading it right (at least that part). But it nowhere tells you to create a new hash before you are going to `verify` (which is what you are doing) ;) The verify functions takes two argument. The password supplied by the user and the hash as saved in the database in the record of the user.

Comment: Just as I said, you are doing it totally wrong. With code like that user can log in using any password. Hash should be computed once, stored in db and retrieved for verification as I answered. Now you are computing hash for whatever submitted password and immediately checking it, without relating it to any user.

Comment: so then I will have to retrieve the row "password" in the db, set hash = to it. and @PeeHaa the problem I am having is that it no where said to do the lookup, that is just ignorance in my part.

Comment: @RaGe10940 :) Basically what you need to do is the following: 1. retrieve the hash from the db. 2. use both the hash you got from the db and the supplied password the user supplied in the form in the `verify()` function. 3. when the supplied password is valid run the hash through `password_needs_rehash`. 4. if the password needs a rehash, hash it again just like you did when the user signed up (`password_hash`) and save the new hash in the database

Comment: I fallow you for everything you said accept for the rehash. I did look into the rehash but why would it need to be done? that part confuses me.

Comment: @RaGe10940 When a user registers on your site a hash is created based on the current safest settings. However while time passes by, computers get faster and hashing algorithms get broken. In order to make sure the stored hashes are keeping up with this you will need to ensure the saved hashes are kept "up to date". A simple example is that currently the safest thing to use in PHP right now is `bcrypt`. However I can see PHP supporting the safer `scrypt` later.

Comment: ah, so its for later down the road kinda situation. alright. thank you - again.